# Word VSTO: Save a string as an AutoText value

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I am porting a Word vba project that has some older WordBasic elements into a VSTO project using vb.net.  One of the tasks I need to do is programmatically save a string, or the contents of a text box on a form, to an AutoText value in the Word template.

In the old project, this was easy.  The command looked something like this:

```
WordBasic.SetAutoText "AT Name", strSomeValue, 0
```

Attempting this in vb.net:

```
'declarations
Public appWord As Word.Application
Public tplMyTpl As Word.Template
Public doc As Word.Document

'Get the template    
appWord = Me.Application
doc = appWord.ActiveDocument
tplMyTpl = doc.AttachedTemplate

'try saving autotext
tplMyTpl.AutoTextEntries.Add("AT Name", strSomeValue)
```

does not work because the AutoTextEntries.Add method only accepts the value as a Word.Range.  A type cast error is thrown at runtime with the code above.  It would have to look something like:

```
dim sel as Word.Selection = appWord.Selection
tplMyTpl.AutoTextEntries.Add("AT Name", sel.Range)
```

Problem is I do not want to insert the string into my document, select it as a Range, save the AutoText entry then delete the text.  That seems like extremely sloppy coding.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind as you convert this is that AutoText as an entity doesn't really exist in Word, anymore. The concept was extended and now is called BuildingBlocks. AutoText is a "Gallery" within BuildingBlocks. For reasons of backwards compaitibilty the old commands still work, but you should consider whether to migrate to the newer object model concept which allows you to break up BuildingBlocks into Categories and Galleries.

Comment: The reason the method's require a Range is that often formatting should be included as part of the BuildingBlock, not just a string. The only "reasonable" way to pick up formatting is by pointing the method to a Range. If you don't want to be doing this in the "real" document (or template) you could create a hidden, "temp" document for creating the entries. Then just close that document without saving.

Comment: Another possible approach would be to manage the BuildingBlock entries via Word Open XML, writing directly to the file rather than working through the object model. Just throwing out the idea...

Comment: Is there a way to select the contents of a RichTextBox as a Word.Range without actually inserting it into the document body first?  I tried looking for a method this way prior to posting but could find none.  DanL's solution works perfectly, but I can think of other uses of being able to save AutoText from a RTB.

Comment: What kind of Rich Text box? If it's not a content control or other "native" Word object, then no. a Word.Range must be part of Word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `WordBasic` in VSTO. Just call it through your `Word.Application` object reference, e.g.:

```
appWord.WordBasic.SetAutoText("AT Name", strSomeValue, 0)
```

Tested and working in Word 2013.